# Modernizr querying my page again after it has loaded?

Tags: javascript, frontend, modernizr

Just noticed that the Controller for a page on my website was hit twice during a single refresh - checking the Network panel indicates that a second GET request (with no additional querystring parameters) was initiated by Modernizr.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: That's rather untypical. Could you provide additional Information such as a link or Screenshot?

Comment: you'll need to provide more information. what is the request? can you share the site?